# Bundle install corrupts my Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a [rapidshare-ext](https://rubygems.org/gems/rapidshare-ext) gem, it depends on [rapidshare](https://rubygems.org/gems/rapidshare) gem.
Have a gem entry in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rapidshare-ext', '0.0.5'
```

In my Gemfile.lock I see the whole gem dependecies:

```
...
rapidshare (0.5.3)
  activesupport (~> 3.2.8)
  curb (~> 0.8.1)
  progressbar (~> 0.11.0)
  rake (~> 0.9.2)
rapidshare-ext (0.0.5)
  rapidshare (~> 0.5.3)
  rest-client (~> 1.6.7)
...
```

All works fine. Try to update gem version to 0.0.6:

```
gem 'rapidshare-ext', '0.0.6'
```

After I run **bundle install** the Gemfile.lock looks like:

```
...
rapidshare-ext (0.0.6)
...
```

All dependecies like rapidshare, rest-client are disappeared and gem became a non-working (require path missed). If I delete Gemfile.lock and then run **bundle install again** all will be fine. How can I fix this behaviour? **bundle update rapidshare-ext** gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something broken in the rubygems/bundlers dependency check API
I replaced rubygems source with and everything went ok

`source "http://bundler-api.herokuapp.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Shitirlic is right Bundler is broken check this out
http://hone.heroku.com/bundler%20heroku/2012/10/22/rubygems-and-the-dependency-api.html